# Coldfusion 8 - Possible to change log file location for site on shared server?

Tags: logging, coldfusion

Is it possible to change log file location for site on shared server without access to the CF administrator?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the CF Admin API, debugging.cfc, using the setLogProperty function
http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=basiconfig_37.html

```
public void setLogProperty ( required propertyName, required propertyValue
)

Sets a specified logging property. To use this method, pass the property in the propertyName attribute and the associated value in the propertyValue attribute.

Output: suppressed
Parameters:
propertyName: any, required, propertyName – Property to set. Valid Properties are:

    LogDirectory
    MaxFileSize
    MaxArchives
    LogScheduledTask
    LogCorbaCalls
    LogRequestTimeLimit
    logMailSeverity
    logMailSentMessages

propertyValue: any, required, propertyValue – Value for propertyName.
```

Read more: http://www.cfexecute.com/admin-api-documentation/debugging-cfc/#ixzz1cYac2yJI